# React Redux doesn't show data in table

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, react-bootstrap-table

I am new in react-redux. I'm trying to load a list of clubs into the table from api link, but unsuccessfully. Can someone help me show a list of clubs in the table?

In actions/clubAction.js

in api/ClubApi I defined getClubs with axios.get(apiUrl+'clubs')

```
import * as types from "./actionTypes";
import * as clubApi from "../../api/clubApi";

export function loadClubSuccess(clubs) {
  return { type: types.LOAD_CLUBS_SUCCESS, clubs };
}

export function loadClubs() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return clubApi
      .getClubs()
      .then(({clubs}) => {
        dispatch(loadClubSuccess(clubs));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
}
```

In reducers/clubReducer.js

In the reducer I added initialState.clubs which I defined in the initialState file as clubs:[]

```
import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";
import initialState from "./initialState";

export default function clubReducer(state = initialState.clubs, action) {
  switch (action.types) {
    case types.LOAD_CLUBS_SUCCESS:
      return action.clubs;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In ClubsPage.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as clubActions from "../../../store/actions/clubActions";
import ClubList from "./ClubList";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

class ClubsPage extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { clubs, actions } = this.props;

    if (clubs.length === 0) {
      actions.loadClubs().catch(error => {
        alert("Loading club failed" + error);
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <h2>Klubovi</h2>
        <ClubList
            clubs={this.props.clubs}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

ClubsPage.propTypes = {
  clubs: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    clubs: state.clubs 
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      loadClubs: bindActionCreators(clubActions.loadClubs, dispatch)
    }
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ClubsPage);
```

In ClubList.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

const columns = [
    {
        dataField: 'id',
        text: 'Id'
    }, 
    {
        dataField: 'name',
        text: 'Naziv kluba'
    }, 
    {
        dataField: 'email',
        text: 'E-Mail'
    }
]

const ClubList = ({ clubs }) => (
    <BootstrapTable 
        keyField='id' 
        data={ clubs } 
        columns={ columns } 
    />
);

ClubList.propTypes = {
  clubs: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default ClubList;
```

Comment: can you share what is the state of redux after the api call has been done with?

Comment: you need to console.log data in different places to see what is happening.  When you call action `actions.loadClubs()` you should not apply `.catch` block

Comment: @KonstantinModin when I put console.log(clubs) in clubAction function loadClubs I get array of clubs, but when I put console.log(this.props.clubs) in Clubspage.js I get empty array

Comment: please debug this with redux dev tools and share your findings

Comment: In the reducer try changing `return action.clubs;` to `return [...action.clubs];` and see if it works.

Comment: @diedu In redux dev tools in action tab I get a number of clubs while in the state tab I get clubs: [] (empty)

Comment: @usafder changed, it's not working

Comment: @AnkushVerma in redux state is empty values, clubs; []

Comment: add 'redux-logger' as middleware , for development, would help a lot .

Comment: @AnkushVerma I solved my problem. The problem occurred in the reducer class clubReducer.js in the switch-case loop. I should have written action.type, not action.types. Anyway, thank you for your instructions.